# Spring boot - Cannot turn off logging

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot

I am trying to turn off the console output in STS for a spring boot application using the application.properties file.

Setting the value logging.level.root does seem to have some effect but I can never turn it off completely and nor can I turn off the auto configuration report output.

```
logging.level.root=OFF
spring.main.banner-mode=OFF
application.version=@project.version@
```

The banner does get turned off by the property spring.main.banner-mode.

For some reason with the above properties I still get DEBUG output from spring on startup:

```
 2017-05-09 15:33:16.744 DEBUG 11772 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application started with classpath:
 2017-05-09 15:33:16.798 DEBUG 11772 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class
```

There are more lines telling me which properties files are being loaded but I dont want to fill up this post with them.

Following from this I then get the autoconfiguration report output.

I am wondering if I have a configuration issue and if this would cause spring to continue to output on start up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer my own question: after trial and error, I finally ended up with the following which suppresses all output on startup via the `application.properties` file:

```
 logging.level.root=OFF
 logging.level.org.springframework.boot=OFF
 spring.main.banner-mode=OFF
```

Comment: this `logging.level.root=OFF` hide all the log  completely.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to the the package of your choice.

```
logging.level.<package>=OFF
```

`logging.level.root=OFF` doesn´t work for me

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework.*=OFF doesnt seem to have any effect either.

Comment: I think it is without _.*_ just _logging.level.org.springframework=OFF_

Comment: I tried it without the '*' and with just the '.' after too, nothing works. I have tried to turn it off in application.yml too and that also doesnt turn off debugging completely, I still get DEBUG output from spring boot.

Comment: I guess I will have to try by creating a custom logback.xml but I dont really understand why which is frustrating!

Comment: One thing I have noticed is setting root level logger to off means I only get DEBUG output from spring on start up, removing this I get DEBUG and INFO output. So setting the root debugger to off has some effect, just no the desired effect.

Comment: I wonder if the properties I posted in my answer will suppress the output in your applications?

Comment: As fas as I know _logging.level.root=OFF_ turns off logging. However if you specify another level for another package it will override previous rule. So, _logging.level.root=OFF logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG_ will log debug level in org.springframework.web package

Comment: Im not specifying anything just using the springboot starters and @SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that it only configures the root level logger; individual logs will be turned back on if the matching logger properties are set (e.g. `logging.level.org.springframework.boot=DEBUG`).  I'm guessing that's why your [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43886432/1108305) needed to explicitly disable the `org.springframework.boot` logger as well as the root logger.

One approach to completely disable logging would be to create a special `logback.xml` file that disables logging completely.

```xml
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

If you *always* want logging turned off, you can just create the `logback.xml` file and put it in the root package (e.g. `src/main/resources/logback.xml`).  If you only want it disabled in certain scenarios (e.g. if in a "nologging" Spring [profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition-profiles)), you could create a custom file with a different name (`logback-off.xml`) and specify that as the config file for the profiles/cases where you want it disabled.

```yaml
logging.config=classpath:logback-off.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who still couldn't fix problem. I was calling jar file to create some objects. The class in that jar file was writing unwanted log. I tried everything, went through so many forums.

So solution for me was to set ROOT to only ERROR:

In `application.yml`

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: ERROR
    com.mypackage: INFO
    org.springframework.*: INFO
```

**So, this way only errors will be shown in the log but also info logs that you have configured.**

I'm putting here some codes I've tried didn't work for me but may work for someone else:

In `application.yml`,
I tried this:

```
logging:
  level:
    com.organization.package: OFF
```

I tried this:

```
logging:
  level:
    com.organization.package.*: OFF
```

I tried this:

```
ClassThatLogsUnwanted class = new ClassThatLogsUnwanted();
Logger.getLogger(class.getName()).setLevel(Level.OFF);
```